# PhysicsEditor Polygon Path to CGPath

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is there a way I can export a physicsbody polygon path from PhysicsEditor (from Code and Web) as a CGPath? I feel there may be an easier way than for me to manually convert from `(72, 429)  , (77, 423)  , (77, 425)  , (-64, 437) ...` into `[CGPoint(x: 72, y: 429), CGPoint(x: 77, y: 423) ...` etc. I can't find much info online. Thanks

**Edit:** I have figured out a way to do this in the xcode playground using `string.replacingOccurrences(of:...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own extractor template and extract it to a plist of strings that could then be read by NSArray.

Now I am not going to go over that process, you can check out the resources over at Code And Web to see how to make that.

The string must be in `{x,y}` format

Once you have it in the plist format, you can then load it into an `NSArray`, and iterate through the array like so:

```
let polygon = CGMutablePath()
polygon.move(to:CGPoint.zero)
let array = NSArray(fileNamed:"polygon")
for strPoint in array
{
   let point = CGPointFromString(strPoint)
   polygon.addLine(to:point)
}
polygon.closeSubpath()
```

'Note if you need an example of how the plist should look like for an NSArray, you can create one via the `New File` method,  and then open it in an XML capable text editor.